# Does a magic weapon's enhancement damage add to at will powers' damage that only use an ability mod for damage?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, weapons

Does a magic weapon's enhancement damage add to at-will powers' damage that only use an ability mod for damage?

EX: A hand crossbow +2 (PC has DEX 18/+4 and Int 18/+4)

When used with Preparatory Shot, which does Dex and Int mod damage, do you add the +2 to the damage, making it a Prep Shot 10 damage?

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

Enhancement bonuses give a bonus to damage *rolls*. If you don't roll for damage, you don't get to add it.

(This is why the latest version of Magic Missile specifically calls out that you *can* add your enhancement bonus, since by default you would not)

Comment: So it would work if the flavor text say something like "Hit 1[W] + Dex Mod + Cha Mod" from Sky Flourish.

Comment: Also, does this mean that feats like "Weapon Focus: +1 damage to weapon group" does not add the +1 damage to the Preparatory Shot even though the Power requires a Ranged "weapon" to use it. It make no sense, since it obvious that the weapon is doing the damage.

But you can still use Preparatory Shot with Sneak Attack ability and Back Stabber feat dealing  Dex + Int mod and Xd8 damage practically every turn.

Comment: For your first comment; yes, if you roll the 1[W] then you add the enhancement bonus. For the second comment; can you make that a separate question? I'm not sure about the answer, so you should probably give others a chance to see it as well.